# Show table headers on each page

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a table that takes about three pages to display and I'm using the `longtable` package. It's three columns by about 80 rows. On the first page, I have headers for each of the columns. Is there a way to show the headers at the top of the table for each subsequent page?

My table currently looks like this

```
\begin{center}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{table}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}||p{7cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & textbf{Definition} \\
    ... (whole bunch of data)
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finish the header with `\endhead` rather than `\\`

Also remove the `center` environment (it has no effect on `longtable`) and place the `caption` within the table. (`texdoc longtable` should show several examples)

Comment: moving the caption within the table also solved another issue I was having with the numbering not being correct. Double thanks!

Comment: Putting \endhead works however the \hline after the header row is not repeated on each page.  That's an odd problem to solve.

Comment: @cryptic0 if you have a question it's better to ask a question rather than comment on an old answer but the `\hline`  will be repeated if it is specified as being inside the head, and will not be repeated if it is placed after the head.

Comment: If you have `\midrule` after the header, then keep  `\\ `    at the end of the line, and place `\endhead` after `\midrule`.

Comment: @cryptic0 `this & is & the & header \\ \hline \endhead`